# React Navigation - "Cannot read property 'State' of undefined" even though gesture-handler is installed & linked

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

***Problem***

I get the error "Cannot read property 'State' of undefined" when trying to use a stack navigator in React Navigation.  Switch and bottomTabNavs are working perfectly fine.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem that would be amazing!

***What I've tried***

I've already checked to make sure react-native-gesture-handler is installed and linked properly.

My Package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "5.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "fs-extra": "^6.0.1",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.7.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^3.2.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone X\"",
    "apk": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "rename": "node ./bin/rename.js",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.0-rc.2",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.1.6",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "5.2.9",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the pod file was not installed even though react-native link indicated the package was successfully linked.

To solve the issue follow these steps:

1. cd ios
2. Pod install
3. Clean ios folder
4. Run application